# How to provide database credentials for Apache Derby embedded using JPA?

Tags: database, jpa-2.0, derby

I need to connect to Apache Derby embedded using JPA. How can I provide the path of database and database credentials to JPA.

Comment: I needed to connect to embeded derby database from javafx application using JPA ,in this case how can i provide the databae credentials and database path to JPA ,I am using Netbeans IDE to develop the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the URL and username/password inside your `persistence.xml` file:

```
    ...
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
            value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:derby:db1" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
    </properties>
    ...
```

You have lots of options around the format of JDBC URL depending on where your database is located. Check [Database connection examples](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html) for the scenario that matches your use case.

Comment: Yes this works in eclipse. But i am using Netbeans IDE ,I am not able to figure out how to do it in Netbeans.

Comment: If you're using JPA then you'll have a `persistence.xml` file in your project, probably in the `META-INF` directory.

Comment: I will try with you suggestion .Thank you .